# How to get value of mat-option selected?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I've been trying to find a way to pull the value of a selected mat-option with this html/ts pairing.

html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
  <mat-label>TRA Type</mat-label>
  <mat-select
    placeholder="TRA Type"
    id="traType"
    name="traType"
    data-qa="new-tra"
    [(ngModel)]="formSelect"
    required>
      <mat-option id="Regular" name="Regular" value="Regular">Regular</mat-option>
      <mat-option id="Unitary" name="Unitary" value="Unitary">Unitary</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-hint>Required</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts

```js
formSelect: string;
traType = <any>{};
```

When propping up the page locally, `this.traType.value` doesn't prop up the value of the selected mat-option. It comes up as undefined when the expected result would be either "Regular" or "Unitary."

Comment: FYI, `angularjs` and `angular` are two different frameworks. Please remove **Angular JS** word from your title.

Answer (score 0):

`this.traType.value` doesn't show the selected value as you miss `[formControl]` Input binding in `<mat-select>` element.

### Solution:

**Add [formControl]="traType" in `<mat-select>` element.**

```
<mat-select placeholder="TRA Type" 
  id="traType" 
  name="traType" 
  [formControl]="traType" 
  data-qa="new-tra" 
  required>
  ..
</mat-select>
```

[Solution in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ajp7ub)

Note: You are recommended to remove `[(ngModel)]` binding if you use `[formControl]` as [it has been deprecated in Angular v6](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel).

---

### Reference

[Form field features (Sample in HTML)](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/select/overview#form-field-features)